# Converting Date back to user's timezone from Azure Table Storage

Tags: .net, azure, azure-table-storage, timezone-offset, datetimeoffset

It is my understanding that Azure Table Storage stores all datetime fields as UTC AKA Zulu Time.

Currently I am in the UK 11th May 2021 at 18:10. The current TimeZone here is BST (+1:00).

If I serialise that into JSON using the RoundtripKind option

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.syncDates, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind
                });
```

It will be sent to my Web Api as

```
"2021-05-11T18:10:31.740582+01:00"
```

However when it is deserialised into the ASP NET Core controller method arguments it appears as a DateTime with DateTimeKind of Local but no longer has any Time Zone Info.

```
11/05/2021 18:10:31
```

I then write the Date into Azure Table Storage and it will be stored as UTC which is

```
11/05/2021 17:10:31
```

When I retreive the data from the web api to display it to the originating user or someone else who wants to look at their data, it is important to know the correct date and hour in relation to the user.

1. Should I be storing the originating Time offset\zone in a separate field and using that to convert the Date back out again?
2. Should I not be storing as a DateTime at all and using DateTimeOffset or is that pointless as Azure Table Storage will just convert the DTO to UTC as well?

Comment: Which client SDK are you using?

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table 1.0.8

Comment: Give Azure.Data.Tables a try. It’s the latest client which is currently in preview, but will be released soon.

Comment: With this regard, the two SDKs have the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve the offset during serialization/deserialization, yes - you should use the `DateTimeOffset` type instead of `DateTime`.

With regard to Azure Table Storage, while the SDKs support `DateTimeOffset`, unfortunately the service itself does not.  Thus saving a `DateTimeOffset` value to Azure Storage will result in the equivalent UTC `DateTime` being stored, as given by the `.UtcDateTime` property of the `DateTimeOffset`.  When retrieving, you will have a `DateTimeOffset` whose date and time are the equivalent UTC date and time, and the offset will be zero.

Thus, if you really need to keep track of the offset, you'll need to store that in a separate column, and combine the two in your controller upon return.  The `DateTimeOffset.ToOffset` method is the easiest way to do that correctly.

Alternatively, if you only need the date and time parts to be correct, you could fib a little and use a UTC `DateTime` even if the value isn't actually in UTC.  Just call `DateTime.SpecifyKind` with `DateTimeKind.Utc` on the way in, and with `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` on the way out.  You'll loose the offset, but if you don't need it anyway then this can work.

Comment: I have already switched to DTO in the ASPNET controller and will be "combining the two in the controller upon return" as you suggest  in the next couple of days

Comment: Great.  I also added an alternate approach, which isn't exactly recommended but can get the job done - depending on your requirements.

Comment: :-) Your alternative approach of fibbing is exactly what I was doing but my colleague talked me out of it saying "that's the kind of lie that makes rockets fall out of the sky"

Comment: Indeed. :D   What can happen with that is that later on someone else might read from the table storage without understanding you were fibbing at the API layer.